# Select Elements Which Have A Certain Attribute Value with simplexml

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have this result when i do var_dump to $xml

```
`object(SimpleXMLElement)[257]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=1)
      'seq' => string '290' (length=3)
  public 'FIN' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[256]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array (size=1)
          'seq' => string '261' (length=3)
      public 'VAL' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'ATT' => 
        array (size=11)
          0 => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[255]`
```

i need select with simplexml which seq have value 29

Thanks in advance

Comment: what "select" does mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath to find element with attribute 'seq' equal 29. Suppouse, $xml contains simplexml object then

```
$element = $xml->xpath('//*[@seq=29]');
```

Comment: yes i used that but when i do $seq=$xmlglobtech->xpath("//*GROUP[@seq='29']"); i do $req->Fin->Rem i get nothing how can i get the fils of this $req selected

Comment: what is this `*GROUP` ?

Comment: the noeud of have seq =29

Comment: i think that //* or //GROUP ? I don't know `*croup`. But i use only 1st xpath

Comment: yes i used //Group but also nothing when i do var_dump($seq) i found the data but when i do $seq->Fin->Rem nothing

Comment: is that dump of $seq in the question?

Comment: $seq=$xmlglobtech->xpath("//GROUP[@seq='29']");  $seq->Fin->Rem  nothing in result but var_dump($req) gives data

Comment: var_dump show something as `<FIN  seq=261><VAL/><ATT/> `. Why you want Fin->Rem ?

Comment: I do that also but not work i need REM because my goal $seq=$xmlglobtech->xpath("//GROUP[@seq='29']/FIN/REM") but not work

Comment: And `$seq=$xmlglobtech->xpath("//GROUP[@seq='29']/FIN/VAL")` does  work?

Comment: no anything array(size=0) empty the same of $seq=$xmlglobtech->xpath("//GROUP[@seq='29']/FIN/REM")